# Drupal 7 Module Dependencies

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am currently developing a loan application site with a number of modules required for the system. I had managed to create 4 modules. To illustrate my question, here is the situation.

```
Module 1
Module 2 - dependent on Module 1
Module 3 - dependent on Module 1
Module 4 - dependent on Module 2
```

Now if I enable Module 4 without enabling the 3 other modules, drupal asked me to install Module 2 and Module 1 for it is the pre-requisite of Module 4. My question is will the sequence of installation be like as follows ?:

```
Module 1
Module 2
Module 4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they will install in that order.

[Issue 833192](http://drupal.org/node/833192) dealt with this, and was resolved in June of 2010.

You can also check out the source for [includes\install.core.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!install.core.inc/7) to verify this. Search for "Always install required modules first" and you will find the code responsible for ensuring that dependencies are installed first.

Comment: See submit handler yourself: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_modules_submit/7

Comment: How does this actually work: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21install.core.inc/7.x  ?  I see that you can click on the LINKS the code shows up expanded, do I have to paste that code into "includes\install.core.inc" or is it just a description of the code already in the file?